# Cannot make result of Webclient.DownloadString() a public variable

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out how to access the result variable from a different class within the same namespace.

Essentially, I want to get the string held in "result" (located in the code below) and then write it to a SQL database (I have written this section of the code and it is working - it is contained in the public static void Main() section)

```
public class Thestring
{
    public void Writejsontoconsole()
    {
        string url = "urlGoesIHere";


        using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
           string result = client.DownloadString(url);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Change the method from returning `void` to `string` and `return client.DownloadString(url)`. That said, you may want to start learning from the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/

Comment: I think you should go over some basic C# tutorials again.  Methods that are void return nothing so you won’t be able to access the result of the method from where you call it.  Also there is no such thing as a “public variable” in a method, that’s what properties and fields are for so if your method must be void, you have to assign your webclient result to a public property or field.

Comment: Thank you. I take your feedback. Your reply was very helpful, Camilo! Thank you!